# Trying to write a list of dictionaries to csv in Python, running into encoding issues

Tags: python, csv, encoding, dictionary, utf-8

So I am running into an encoding problem stemming from writing dictionaries to csv in Python.

Here is an example code:

```
import csv

some_list = ['jalape\xc3\xb1o']

with open('test_encode_output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    output_file = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for item in some_list:
        output_file.writerow([item])
```

This works perfectly fine and gives me a csv file with "jalapeño" written in it.

However, when I create a list of dictionaries with values that contain such UTF-8 characters...

```
import csv

some_list = [{'main': ['4 dried ancho chile peppers, stems, veins
            and seeds removed']}, {'main': ['2 jalape\xc3\xb1o 
            peppers, seeded and chopped', '1 dash salt']}]

with open('test_encode_output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    output_file = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for item in some_list:
        output_file.writerow([item])
```

I just get a csv file with 2 rows with the following entries:

```
{'main': ['4 dried ancho chile peppers, stems, veins and seeds removed']}
{'main': ['2 jalape\xc3\xb1o peppers, seeded and chopped', '1 dash salt']}
```

I know I have my stuff written in the right encoding, but because they aren't strings, when they are written out by csv.writer, they are written as-is. This is frustrating. I searched for some similar questions on here and people have mentioned using csv.DictWriter but that wouldn't really work well for me because my list of dictionaries aren't all just with 1 key `'main'`. Some have other keys like `'toppings'`, `'crust'`, etc. Not just that, I'm still doing more work on them where the eventual output is to have the ingredients formatted in amount, unit, ingredient, so I will end up with a list of dictionaries like

```
[{'main': {'amount': ['4'], 'unit': [''], 
'ingredient': ['dried ancho chile peppers']}},
{'topping': {'amount': ['1'], 'unit': ['pump'], 
'ingredient': ['cool whip']}, 'filling': 
{'amount': ['2'], 'unit': ['cups'], 
'ingredient': ['strawberry jam']}}]
```

Seriously, any help would be greatly appreciated, else I'd have to use a find and replace in LibreOffice to fix all those \x** UTF-8 encodings.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to be written for each dictionary instead then? All the list values together? Keys? List entries per key as columns?

Comment: You are taking a heterogeneous list and attempting to map it to a homogeneous structure (csv).  Obviously, this will take a little work.  But it's not at all clear what you want the actual output to be.  That makes a *huge* difference in determining a solution.  Please show us the *exact* output you want for a representative input.  Otherwise, we are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Using the example code I have above, I want the output to be {'main': ['4 dried ancho chile peppers, stems, veins', '    and seeds removed']} {'main': ['2 jalapeño peppers, seeded and chopped', '1 dash salt']}

Comment: Ok, but what does that have to do with CSV?  It's not even remotely CSV format.  Also, I'm pretty sure that's not a representative example, because it only has dictionaries with a single 'main' key.  I'm pretty sure you said you have use cases that have other keys as well.  What about those cases?

Comment: row 1: {'main': ['2 jalape\xc3\xb1o peppers, seeded and chopped', '1 dash salt']}
row 2: {'toppings': ['cool whip'], 'filling': ['strawberry jam']}

Another script will then go through the above and yield

row 1: {'main': {'amount': ['2', '1'], 'unit': ['', 'dash'], 'ingredient': ['jalape\xc3\xb1o peppers, seeded and chopped', 'salt']}}
row 2: {'toppings': {'amount': ['as desired'], 'unit': [''], 'ingredient': ['cool whip']}, 'filling': {'amount': ['as desired'], 'unit': [''], 'ingredient': ['strawberry jam']}}

Comment: So you want "jalape\xc3\xb1o" instead of "jalapeño"?  Isn't that what you have now?

Comment: I want "jalapeño". What I get now is "jalape\xc3\xb1o" in the csv output. The backslash is there.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of your previous comment?

Comment: That was my mistake. That's what I'm getting now and I don't want that. I want "jalapeño".

Answer (score 2):

You are writing **dictionaries** to the CSV file, while `.writerow()` expects lists with singular values that are turned into strings on writing.

Don't write dictionaries, these are turned into string representations, as you've discovered.

You need to determine how the keys and / or values of each dictionary are to be turned into columns, where each column is a single *primitive* value.

If, for example, you only want to write the `main` key (if present) then do so:

```
with open('test_encode_output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    output_file = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for item in some_list:
        if 'main' in item:
            output_file.writerow(item['main'])
```

where it is assumed that the value associated with the `'main'` key is always a list of values.

If you wanted to persist dictionaries with Unicode values, then you are using the wrong tool. CSV is a flat data format, just rows and primitive columns. Use a tool that can preserve the right amount of information instead.

For dictionaries with string keys, lists, numbers and unicode text, you can use JSON, or you can use `pickle` if more complex and custom data types are involved. When using JSON, you *do* want to either decode from byte strings to Python Unicode values, or always use UTF-8-encoded byte strings, or state how the [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) should handle string encoding for you with the `encoding` keyword:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(some_list, jsonfile, encoding='utf8')
```

because JSON strings are always unicode values. The default for `encoding` is `utf8` but I added it here for clarity.

Loading the data again:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    some_list = json.load(jsonfile)
```

Note that this *will* return unicode strings, *not* strings encoded to UTF8.

The [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) works much the same way, but the data format is not human-readable:

```
import pickle

# store
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(some_list, pfile)

# load
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as pfile:
    some_list = pickle.load(pfile)
```

`pickle` will return your data **exactly** as you stored it. Byte strings remain byte strings, unicode values would be restored as unicode.

Comment: As stated, this doesn't work because some dictionaries don't have main and instead have multiple keys like `'toppings'`, `'crust'`, etc. Also, I want to maintain the format of the dictionary as a string so that when I read it in using csv.reader, I can just eval(row[0]) and create the dictionary.

Comment: @shabalong: You are using the wrong tool then. You cannot have what you want here; both a round-trippable format *and* readable as CSV in Excel is not achievable with dictionaries.

Comment: @shabalong: what is your *real* use-case here? What are you trying to solve, really? For persistence, use a format that can capture all information you need preserving, ranging from JSON to a SQL database to `pickle`.

Comment: What format would you suggest I read and write the data in then? I need to write it out as a dictionary, and read it in as a dictionary.

Comment: @shabalong: Are the dictionary keys always strings? Are the values always primitive Python types (unicode strings, numbers, lists, other dictionaries)?

Comment: So, firstly, I'm just formatting the ingredients of recipes into a dictionary that has either 1 key, `'main'`, or if the recipe has sub-recipe headers like `'crust'`, `'topping'`, then the keys are the sub-recipe headers. Values are the the lists of ingredients associated. That is the first pass. After that, I'm formatting the ingredients into amount, unit, ingredients while maintaining the distinction between recipes with sub-recipe headers and those without (for which I use `'main'` as a header). An example of how that looks like is in my main post.

Comment: Yes, the dictionary keys are always strings, and the values are always primitive Python types.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in your output, you've used a dictionary so if you want that string to be processed you have to write this:

```
import csv

some_list = [{'main': ['4 dried ancho chile peppers, stems, veins', '\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 and seeds removed']}, {'main': ['2 jalape\xc3\xb1o peppers, seeded and chopped', '1 dash salt']}]

with open('test_encode_output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    output_file = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for item in some_list:
        output_file.writerow(item['main'])  #so instead of [item], we use item['main']
```

I understand that this is possibly not the code you want as it limits you to call every key main but at least it gets processed now.

You might want to formulate what you want to do a bit better as now it is not really clear (at least to me). For example do you want a csv file that gives you main in the first cell and then 4 dried ...